# What is the difference between Func<x,y> and Method(x,y)?

Tags: c#

What is the difference between the 2 methods below ? They both return exactly the same (as far as I know) so i'm wondering why one would rather use the one over the other ?

Is there a specific case in which one of the 2 methods below would be preferable ?
Or are there any situations in which it would be better to use `func<>` over a normal method ?

```
 private static int addThings(int x, int y)
 {
  return x*y;
 }

 private static Func<int,int,int> addMoreThings = (x,y) =>
 {
  return x*y;
 };
```

Comment: One a method, the other is a variable.  Big difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Func` is a *delegate* - (what C++ programmers would call a strongly typed function pointer).

The `Func<int,int,int>` means a delegate for functions that take two integers and return an integer - any such function.

In the case of `addThings`, the calculation is done immediately and the result returned.

In the case of `addMoreThings`, the *function* is returned. It can be later *invoked*.

It is difficult to recommend one over the other without more context - having the delegate version allows you to be lazy - to use the strategy pattern, for example by assigning the strategy to a delegate.