# C# Function Writing

Tags: c#

Simple question on writing code in C#. Is there any value in writing a function in this way

```
Func<int, int> add2 = x => x + 2;
```

as compared to

```
int add2(int x)
{
    return x + 2;
}
```

I find the second example much easier to read, or am I missing a very specific reason for why the 1st function is written that way?

Comment: If it is easy to read, it is easy to maintain so it is the best way to write code.

Comment: C, C#, and C++ are not the same language, and therefore their tags are not synonyms. I've removed the C tag you applied and replaced it with the correct C# tag. Please don't just randomly add tags because they seem similar or familiar - tags have specific meanings and purpose here. Thanks.

Comment: With C# 6.0 we can write `int add2(int x) => x + 2`, which might be easier or harder to read depending on your background

Comment: I have to agree with Max, adding private / protected / public would in my opinion be even better for readability.

Comment: You can create the first one inline inside another method.  For more complex scenarios this can be handy for using variables in the outer scope within the inner function etc, but it doesn't really make any difference for the example presented

Comment: They serve different semantic purposes, neither one is inherently better than the other.  If you need a temporary function that isn't really part of an object and can be passed around in a variable, the first is easier.  If you need a method that is structurally part of an object then the second would likely be more appropriate.

Comment: Do you have any experiance with Linq? If you write a Where clause that looks like `.Where(x => x == 2)` you can see the filter value directly on the use of the expression. If you write a named method you have to jump to the method to see what the filter does... In my opinion it's easyer to see that inline.

Comment: The two are not the same thing, though they can serve some of the same purposes. Here's another question on the same subject: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13663263/what-is-the-difference-between-funcx-y-and-methodx-y

Comment: `Func<T1, T2>` is a delegate, and your second snippet is only valid syntax as an internal instance method in a class. These are not the same thing, conceptually.

Comment: Srry Ken, I didn't realize Tags did not accept C#.. I used Uppercase. It must have converted to lowercase as an error and then removed the '#' symbol. I guess all tags are lowercase then.

Comment: @Verarind This is not LINQ.

Comment: @EBrown Yes I know. It was only a sample that the first notation has a real benefit in readability.

Comment: @EBrown it could be. Both of those `add2` could be passed to a `Select` on an `IEnumerable<int>`.

Comment: @JonHanna They're not LINQ though. The fact that they can be passed **in a LINQ query** does not make them LINQ, it makes them **LINQ compatible.**

Comment: @EBrown So what? It's that they might be that is relevant to a question about advantages of different equivalent forms in C#, unless there is no C# code anywhere in the world that is Linq.

Comment: @JonHanna The OP never asked such a thing, he asked what is the value of using one form over the other. The fact that **both** of them are compatible with LINQ is irrelevant, as it does not make one have an advantage over the other.

Comment: @EBrown if you really think the linq example in my answer using both forms are equally readable, then fair enough, but I'm sure I'm not alone in finding the former example much more readable in a lot of linq code, and indeed that's probably the case where I would favour the former over the latter most often.

Comment: @JonHanna I never said that, in LINQ I use the Lambda style as well, it's much more direct. However, should the OP be doing operations (not a simple addition) to which LINQ is not as readable or effective at [see RayTracer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lukeh/archive/2007/10/01/taking-linq-to-objects-to-extremes-a-fully-linqified-raytracer.aspx), then the second form would be the best option. For code as simple as the question displays, LINQ is not relevant. Each form has advantages. Plus, Intellisense shows the `Func` as a variable in the dropdown, which I would not expect to be a method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one is an Function object, while the second one is just a function/method. The difference is that the first one is an object in the Object hirachy of the .Net platform, and the later one is just a function which is not in that hirachy. But as far as I know C# does autoboxing for you for the second case, whenever you need autoboxing. Another difference might be the appearance of those functions in the reflection api. While the first one is just a variable with a function value, the second one is actually a function in the api.

Comment: "While the first one is just a variable with a function value"

Answer (score 1):

The first one can be considered the equivalent to a **Function Pointer**, which can be empty just waiting to receive a "delegate". In the case you present, its implementation is already declared with a **lambda expression**. The second one is an actual, regular function which might as well be passed as parameter to a `Func` with equivalent template types:

```
int add2(int x)
{
    return x + 2;
}

int main()
{   
    Func<int, int> add2Func = add2;
    // Invoking:
    int retVal = add2Func.Invoke(10); // will call the add2 function
}
```

Answer (score 1):

These two codes are (assuming they are both outside a method) different in meaning. The first one declares a field of type `Func<int, int>` (a delegate taking an `int` and returning `int`), and assigns a lambda expression to it. The second one only declares a normal method with a body. The difference is (other than the first one is a field and the second one is a method) that you can change the value of `add2`, if it is a field.

Lambda expression are useful because they are short to write, use type inference to determine types of the parameters (`x`), and, if not specified as a block, implicitly returning a value. This is why they are mostly used in LINQ, because they can fit well on one line. There is also a second syntax, anonymous method, that looks like this:

```
Func<int, int> add2 = delegate(int x)
{
    return x + 2;
};
```

Anonymous methods have the advatage that you can omit parameters (`delegate{ ... }`), and it matches any delegate type.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as others say, strictly speaking, you are talking about 2 different things.  But your question remains relevant in that, in different situations, you are often faced with having to choose between writing some code using lambda or writing a formal method.

The choice is mainly a matter of style. And I will say that sometimes, some people over use the lambda style just because they are trying to be clever and want to see how much code they can put in as little space as possible.  But it can definitely become harder to read.

Yet, there are definitely instances where using lambdas will improve readability and convenience.

A good example of this is when using it together with chainable LINQ methods.

Which version do you find more readable and convenient?

**Lambda version**

```
List<int> list = new List<int> { 6, 3, 9, 2, 6, 9, 7, 11, -4 };
IEnumerable<int> processedList = list.Where(i => i % 2 == 0).OrderBy(i => i);
```

**Normal method version**

```
List<int> list = new List<int> { 6, 3, 9, 2, 6, 9, 7, 11, -4 };
IEnumerable<int> processedList = list.Where(FilterByNumber).OrderBy(OrderByNumber);

private bool FilterByNumber(int i)
{
    return i % 2 == 0;
}

private int OrderByNumber(int i)
{
    return i;
}
```

Just do what you feel more comfortable with and that won't leave you scratching your head afterwards when you are faced with having to change the code later.

Answer (score 1):

The way to create an equivalent expression to:

```
Func<int, int> add2 = x => x + 2;
```

Is to do:

```
Expression<Func<int, int>> add2 = x => x + 2;
```

Indeed, we don't even need to know which is happening in the code:

```
something.Select(x => x + 2);
```

The compiler creates a delegate (as per the first one) or expression (as per the second) depending on which is more useful. (Most likely `something` is either a `IQueryable<int>` in which case the expression will be produced, or else some other type of `IEnumerable<int>` in which case the `Func` will be produced).

The way to create an equivalent expression to:

```
int add2(int x)
{
  return x + 2;
}
```

(That is to say, avoiding lambda syntax), is:

```
var parExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "x");
var lamda = Expression.Lambda<Func<int, int>>(
    Expression.Add(parExp, Expression.Constant(2, typeof(int))), parExp);
```

In comparison to which, I'd say that `x => x + 2` is much more readable.

There are less extreme cases where the lambda syntax can be immediately more readable, a particular case being where you are using several in a row, as often happens with Linq though certainly also in plenty of other cases.

It also adds to the readability of the application as a whole that small simple methods like `add2` are only defined where used*, rather than filling classes with lots of such methods. Consider this slightly-modified real-world code:

```
var lastModAndTag = await ctx.Pending
  .Select(pn => new {pn.Modified, pn.Tag})
  .Union(ctx.Preferences.Select(pr => new {pr.Modified, pr.Tag}))
  .OrderByDescending(dt => dt.Modified).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

With the following:

```
private class DateAndTag // Can't use anonymous types as we have to pass method boundaries.
{
  public DateTime Modified { get; set; }
  public string Modified { get; set; }
}
private static DateAndTagFromPending(Pending pn)
{
  return new DateAndTag{Modified = pn.Modified, Tag = pn.Tag};
}
private static DateAndTagFromPreference(Preference pr)
{
  return new DateAndTag{Modified = pr.Modified, Tag = pr.Tag};
}
private static DateTime GetModified(DateAndTag dt)
{ //it's possible to get the property into a method or delegate with reflection, but that's even worse.
  return dt.Modified;
}
//and now in the calling code;
var lastModAndTag = ctx.Pending
  .Select(DateAndTagFromPending)
  .Union(ctx.Preferences.Select(DateAndTagFromPreference))
  .OrderByDescending(GetModified).FirstOrDefault();
```

That's really not easier to read. And also we couldn't use `Async` because that only works with expressions. Indeed we were forced to grab everything from the database to run these functions on them. But even if we didn't care (because we were working in-memory and using `Func`) it's still much more code to wade through.

Finally, if you need to curry or otherwise capture variables then your choice is in fact between:

```
Func<int, int> addX = val => val + x; // x is from outside of this step.
```

And:

```
Func<int, int> addX = delegate(int val)
{
  return val + x;
};
```

Which right now might seem more readable to you if you're not used to the lambda form, but certainly doesn't to me.

And indeed the more one gets used to the lambda form, the more one will use it just because it seems more readable.

If however you have a method that is of any complexity, **or** is recursive, **or** needs to be an accessible method, then the lambda form would not be as helpful.

*Though note that if you have two methods identical to `add2` the compiler will often merge them into a single delegate in the assembly produced, so such repetition in source isn't wasteful or something to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's better to use `Func<T2,T2,...,Tn>` instead of static function declaration.

Example: you have a generic method for convert object from Type1 to Type2

```
public Tout Convert<Tin, Tout>(Tin obj, Func<Tin, Tout> convertFunc)
{
   return convertFunc(obj);
}
```

...

```
Class1 obj = new Class1();
Class2 convertedObject = Convert<Class1, Class2>(obj, x => new Class2());
```

What are benefits? Lambda expression is shorter and and code more readable.